# Importing Cancelled Transactions?

Tags: civicontribute

We use several different payment processors, and I'd like to try to import into Civi not only the completed transactions but also the failed transactions, along with the failure reason. This will help us follow up with these members and track their giving over time.

I was able to import the contributions such that they show "Cancelled" in the Contribution Status field, however the Cancelled/Refunded Date and the Cancellation / Refund Reason fields do not appear on the contribution record. On the contribution tab, the Cancelled contributions I uploaded appear in a black font, rather than the greyed out font for iATS cancellations.

Any thoughts on this? One thing I haven't tried is to import a Cancellation Date along with the Reason - perhaps the two go hand in hand.

Thank you!

Civi 5.7.6 on Drupal 7

Comment: if you are saying those fields do not import, you could take a look at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/blob/master/README